# Can anybody to solve gauss looping error?

Tags: loops

I am unable to solve the problem.

```
vd1  = ir1.^2;
vd2  = ir1.^2 + ir2.^2;
vd2  = 100*vd2./sumc(vd2');
vd3  = ir1.^2 + ir2.^2 + ir3.^2;
vd3  = 100*vd3./sumc(vd3');
vd4  = ir1.^2 + ir2.^2 + ir3.^2 + ir4.^2;
vd4  = 100*vd4./sumc(vd4');
vd5  = ir1.^2 + ir2.^2 + ir3.^2 + ir4.^2 + ir5.^2;
vd5  = 100*vd5./sumc(vd5');
vd6  = ir1.^2 + ir2.^2 + ir3.^2 + ir4.^2 + ir5.^2 + ir6.^2;
vd6  = 100*vd6./sumc(vd6');
vd7  = ir1.^2 + ir2.^2 + ir3.^2 + ir4.^2 + ir5.^2 + ir6.^2 + ir7.^2;
vd7  = 100*vd7./sumc(vd7');
vd8  = ir1.^2 + ir2.^2 + ir3.^2 + ir4.^2 + ir5.^2 + ir6.^2 + ir7.^2 + ir8.^2;
vd8  = 100*vd8./sumc(vd8');
vd9  = ir1.^2 + ir2.^2 + ir3.^2 + ir4.^2 + ir5.^2 + ir6.^2 + ir7.^2 + ir8.^2 + ir9.^2;
vd9  = 100*vd9./sumc(vd9');
vd10 = ir1.^2 + ir2.^2 + ir3.^2 + ir4.^2 + ir5.^2 + ir6.^2 + ir7.^2 + ir8.^2 + ir9.^2 + ir10.^2;
vd10 = 100*vd10./sumc(vd10');
```

and I want to sum up vd1 to vd10.

so I use the loop.

```
tr=0;
i=1;
do intil i>10;
tr = tr + vd[i];
i=i+1;
endo;
```

but error occur.
How I can handel this?
please help me...

Comment: Can you specify a language or at least add some formatting to your question so it is more comprehensive what you are trying to do?

Comment: Sorry for this.. It's GAUSS CODE. I explained the title. It's Gauss code..

Comment: And I'm just sum up vd1 to vd10 using loop. but error occur...

Answer (score 0):

You should write:

```
do until i >= 10;
```

Remark : if you want to sum up vd1 to vd10, it seems that you should use the >= operator.

Comment: I revised it. but error occur again... I think the error occur because trying to index into a matrix named vd[i].